# Colocar los elementos mediante flex

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

quiero colocar el siguiente formulario de registro con este aspecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello iba a hacerlo con `display: flex;` Según yo entiendo este sirve para describir como se han de ordenar los **contenedores**. Por lo tanto yo he hecho un contenedor general, "contenedor-registro" y luego 3 contenedores para conseguir la forma que yo quiero.

Entiendo que al contenedor principal, debo definirlo con una dirección de tipo fila, `flex-direction:column;` y automáticamente todo debería ponerse en columna, el del formulario que contiene los inputs como `flex-direction:row;` y luego a los dos que contienen los campos de texto un `flex-direction:column;`.

¿Porque no se me pone en fila el form?

**Código**

```css
/* ++++++++++ CONTENEDORES DE REGISTRO Y LOGIN ++++++++++++ */

#contenedor-btn-registro-login {
  background-color: #f4a9c7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#contenedor-btn-registro-login a {
  background-color: #fff78c;
  padding: 7px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 30px;
}

.contenedor-registro-login {
  background-color: #f4a9c7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contenedor-registro-login h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.contenedor-registro-login input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.contenedor-registro-login p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}


/* ++++++++++ FORMULARIO REGISTRO ++++++++++++ */
#contenedor-registro{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

#form-registro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.registrotext {
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor contenedor-registro-login" id="contenedor-registro">

  <h2>PAG REGISTRO</h2>

  <div id="form-registro">
    <form action="PHP/LogIn/validarRegistro.php" method="post">

      <div class="registrotext">
        <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="nombre" required autofocus placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="text" name="txtUsuario" id="Usuario" required placeholder="Usuario">
      </div>

      <div class="registrotext">
        <input type="email" name="txtEmail" id="email" required placeholder="email">
        <input type="password" name="txtClave" required placeholder="Contraseña">
      </div>
      <div id="registro-submit">
        <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Registrar">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <p>Cuidado porque es Case Sensitive</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El div `#form-registro` tiene dentro un solo elemento: `form`. Por tanto tienes que hacer el formulario un contenedor flex:  `#form-registro form{` en lugar de `#form-registro{`

```css
/* ++++++++++ CONTENEDORES DE REGISTRO Y LOGIN ++++++++++++ */


.contenedor-registro-login {
  background-color: #f4a9c7;

}

.contenedor-registro-login h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.contenedor-registro-login input, #btn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.contenedor-registro-login p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}


/* ++++++++++ FORMULARIO REGISTRO ++++++++++++ */
#contenedor-registro{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

#form-registro form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.registrotext {
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


#registro-submit{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor contenedor-registro-login" id="contenedor-registro">

  <h2>PAG REGISTRO</h2>

  <div id="form-registro">
    <form action="PHP/LogIn/validarRegistro.php" method="post">

      <div class="registrotext">
        <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="nombre" required autofocus placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="text" name="txtUsuario" id="Usuario" required placeholder="Usuario">
      </div>

      <div class="registrotext">
        <input type="email" name="txtEmail" id="email" required placeholder="email" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="password" name="txtClave" required placeholder="Contraseña">
      </div>
      <div id="registro-submit">
        <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Registrar">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <p>Cuidado porque es Case Sensitive</p>

</div>
```

Espero que sea útil